# Android locked MicroSD card (all files read-only)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, file-system, storage, file-permissions

I own a Wiko Rainbow with Android 4.2.2. Out of the blue my MicroSD card got locked and I can neither create nor delete any files on my phone (such as photos). At first, I did not even understand why, until I checked the file permissions in the AndroZip file manager. All files and folders have been set to read-only.

I tried restarting my phone, but nothing changed. I also unmounted and reattached the MicroSD card in the Android settings. I opened my phone, removed and checked the card, but it did not help. The card has no mechanical write lock.

How come that Android locks my MicroSD card? I did not install any new software, my phone is unrooted and all I do is update my apps occasionally. I read that Android 4.4 had some issues with memory cards. Did Google maybe lock the MicroSD card with an update?

How can I fix the problem and make the card writable again (and prevent future locks). I do not own any MicroSD card reader, so the only solution is creating a backup of the card's content and reformatting it in Android, right?

Do Android or my apps store any data on the SD card (such as user settings or contacts)?

Comment: Open a terminal and run the `mount` command. Is there a `errors=remount,ro` at your card? That may have occured during boot when errors were found,

Comment: Exactly my guess, too. Additionally, you could [check the system logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) for hints.

Comment: @ott: As mentioned, I do not have a card reader (yet). But if the ``errors`` property would be set as you mentioned, how would I fix that? Alternatively, would it solve the problem if I reformat the card within the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write files on your external SD card? Google has blocked the write access to External SD card for third party apps on Android 4.4. Lots of apps became useless on KitKat. You can try upgrading your Android system to 5.0+. Also please try using your mobile default file manager to read or write files to see what will happen.